# grep search two lines in a text file

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I'm trying to grep a html file.

Search text:

```
Ready to be merged automatically
</h4>

grep -A1 "Ready to be merged automatically"
```

prints two lines but how can i use it in a if statement?

```
if " Ready to be merged automatically
    </h4>"
found do something.
```

Html file could have multiple entries of `</h4>` and `Ready to be merged automatically`, but it only has one entry together.

Comment: use `-q` option... see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48535/can-grep-return-true-false-or-are-there-alternative-methods

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @Sundeep `grep -q` will just tell if the first line is found, it won't tell if it's followed by `</h4>`

Comment: This seems like a better job for `awk`. When you match the first line, read another line and test if it matches the second line.

Comment: not sure why this question was marked not useful. I searched everwhere, grep -q won't tell if its followed by </h4>.

Comment: @Barmar oh ok, I hadn't read the question properly then... `awk` would be better fit as you point out... `awk 'p ~ /Ready to be merged automatically/ && /<\/h4>/{print "matched"} {p = $0}' file`

Comment: @Sundeep - thank you, above awk statement worked.

Comment: grep -Pzo 'Ready to be merged automatically.*\n.*</h4>' file, if anyone needed a one liner in grep.